# Git block commit to specific folder

Tags: git

I would like to block or lock all commit to one specific C# project of my solution. So to one specific folder. Is it possible to do this with Git (with Bitbucket).

I ask this question because it seems impossible and this seems a so important feature that i think I must miss something.

Comment: Yes, totally do-able with a commit hook. See https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Comment: And can I use hook on bitbucket?

Comment: That Im not so sure about. Have you looked at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Push

Answer (score -3, accepted):

one way to achieve this is just add that folder to `.gitignore`

[More about gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: .gitignore is not used for handling permissions. It is used for convenience. Anything specified in .gitignore can easily be overridden by `git add -f`. Also, even if that was not possible, .gitignore has no impact on modification of existing tracked files. .gitignore only has effect for untracked files.